# Exception and endlessly growing designer generated code in InitializeComponent when using Steema TeeChart for .NET 2013 4.1.2013.05280 - What to do?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, teechart

When using a Gantt series in a TeeChart control of Steema TeeChart for .NET 2013 4.1.2013.05280 in VS2010, the following exception occurs within the chart after saving and reopening the parent form.

[image: Exception when opening a previously saved form]

Several tries to open the form later, the Designer magically works again, but it has added an awful lot of new resources to the form's .resx file (and accesses them in InitializeComponent respectively).

[image: OMG, so much growing code :-o]

This behavior can be reproduced with any application using a simple Windows Form, that contains a TeeChart control and a default gantt series with random values. I fear this is a followup bug to TF02016535, that has been fixed in this build.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for reporting. I could reproduce the issue and added it (TF02016626) to the defect list to be fixed for next releases. We have found that in VS2012 saving the form (form only, not the complete project) before closing it doesn't produce the exception. Alternatively, the only solution I can think of for now is using Gantt series at run-time, for example:

> ```
>   Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Gantt gantt1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Gantt(tChart1.Chart);
>
>   gantt1.FillSampleValues();
> ```

Comment: It has been a while, but finally had the time to test again with TeeChart 4.1.2013.11081 Unfortunately this new version produces designer code that cannot be compiled anymore. Namely this.gantt1.MultipleNextTasks = ((System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<int>>)(resources.GetObject("gantt1.MultipleNextTasks"))); leads to: Property or indexer 'Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Gantt.MultipleNextTasks' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: Hello @NullAndVoid, Thanks for your information. I can reproduce the problem. Could you please add your request to http://bugs.teechart.net/ ? Doing so you'll be identified as the creator of the issue and therefore notified about its evolution.  Thanks,