# TeeChart Gantt chart "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled" error

Tags: c#, indexoutofboundsexception, teechart, gantt-chart

In a test app I was building I came across this error when trying to draw the chart.  I have some pseudo-randomly generated data that crashes my test app when trying to draw the Gantt chart...

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled HResult=-2146233086
>   Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the
>   size of the collection. Parameter name: index ParamName=index
>   Source=mscorlib StackTrace: at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument
>   argument, ExceptionResource resource) at
>   Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Gantt.CopyNextTasks() at
>   Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Gantt.Draw() at
>   Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Series.DrawSeries() at
>   Steema.TeeChart.Chart.DoDraw(Graphics3D g, Int32 First, Int32 Last,
>   Int32 Inc) at Steema.TeeChart.Chart.DrawAllSeries(Graphics3D g) at
>   Steema.TeeChart.Chart.InternalDraw(Graphics g, Boolean noTools) at
>   Steema.TeeChart.Chart.InternalDraw(Graphics g) at
>   Steema.TeeChart.TChart.Draw(Graphics g) at
>   Steema.TeeChart.TChart.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e,
>   Int16 layer) at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m) at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam) InnerException:

It appears to be way down in the TeeChart Gantt chart drawing logic.

My project is here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/haqspd4ux41n2uf/AADkj2H5GLd09oJTW-HrAVr3a?dl=0

if anyone wants to reproduce it.

This test code did used to execute correctly with old 2.0.2670.26520 version of TeeChart.

Seems like my error might be related to the one described here:
[Exception and endlessly growing designer generated code in InitializeComponent when using Steema TeeChart for .NET 2013 4.1.2013.05280 - What to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345334/exception-and-endlessly-growing-designer-generated-code-in-initializecomponent-w)

Any ideas or suggestions on getting around it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error in your code which can be reproduced with this simple code snippet:

```
  Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Gantt series = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Gantt(tChart1.Chart);

  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    series.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i), DateTime.Now.AddDays(i+5), i, "task " + i.ToString());
    series.NextTasks[series.Count - 1] = series.Count;
  }
```

When the loop reaches its last iteration (i = 9), *NextTasks[9]* is being set to 10, an index that doesn't exist (series ranges from 0 to 9) and which causes the index out of range error you get. The solution is making sure that index is never assigned, for example:

```
  const int max = 10;
  for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
  {
    series.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i), DateTime.Now.AddDays(i+5), i, "task " + i.ToString());
    series.NextTasks[series.Count - 1] = (i < max - 1) ? series.Count : -1;
  }
```

The same in your code would be something like this:

```
      crewSeries.NextTasks[crewSeries.Count - 1] = (crewSeries.Count == crewDataView.Count - 1) ? -1 : crewSeries.Count;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Narcis. I think I understand where I was going wrong. The last task for each series must end with a -1. However, I'm not sure your suggestion is completely correct.
 
I think: 

`crewSeries.NextTasks[crewSeries.Count - 1] = (crewSeries.Count == crewDataView.Count - 1) ? crewSeries.Count : -1;`

should be: 
`crewSeries.NextTasks[crewSeries.Count - 1] = (crewSeries.Count <= crewDataView.Count - 1) ? crewSeries.Count : -1;`

Comment: Yes, exactly, you are right. I corrected my answer to use:           crewSeries.NextTasks[crewSeries.Count - 1] = (crewSeries.Count == crewDataView.Count - 1) ? -1 : crewSeries.Count;. The point is not that the last task in the series should point to -1 but should point to an existing index within the 0 to crewSeries.Count - 1 range.